# Why does Visual Studio say my input string is not in a correct format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The following code:

```
string year = textBoxYear.Text;
string award = comboBoxAwards.Text;
string cat = comboBoxCategory.Text;
string title = textBoxTitle.Text;
string author = textBoxAuthor.Text;
string kindleASIN = textBoxKindleASIN.Text;
string hardboundASIN = textBoxHardboundASIN.Text;
string paperbackASIN = textBoxPaperbackASIN.Text;
string imgSrc = getImgSrc(kindleASIN, hardboundASIN, paperbackASIN);
string newRec = // Keeping year as int for LINQ querying (where year > or < such and such), and yearDisplay spans two years for some awards
    string.Format(
        "new BookClass{Award=\"{0}\", Year={1}, YearDisplay=\"{1}\", Category=\"{2}\", Title=\"{3}\", Author=\"{4}\", KindleASIN=\"{5}\", HardboundASIN=\"{6}\", PaperbackASIN=\"{7}\", ImgSrc=\"{8}\"},", award, year, cat, title, author, kindleASIN, hardboundASIN, paperbackASIN, imgSrc);
```

...using this data:

```
year = "2013"
award = "Hugos"
cat = "Best Novel"
title == "Redshirts"
author == "John Scalzi"
kindleASIN == "B0079XPUOW"
hardboundASIN == "0765316994"
paperbackASIN == "0765334798"
imgSrc == "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B0079XPUOW.01.MZZZZZZZ"
```

...dies on the assignment to imgSrc, saying: "*System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format*".

...and the "Troubleshooting tips" says, "*When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.*"

But I'm not converting a string to DateTime...What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show us `getImgSrc()`?

Comment: What does `getImgSrc` look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your curly braces that are not replacement tokens are messing it up

```
new BookClass{Award=\"{0}\", Year={1}, YearDisplay=\"{1}\"
      here --^
```

You need to escape any `{` or `}` you use by doubling them, they will show up as a single curly brace after the `Format` function processes the string.

```
string.Format(
        "new BookClass{{Award=\"{0}\", Year={1}, YearDisplay=\"{1}\", Category=\"{2}\", Title=\"{3}\", Author=\"{4}\", KindleASIN=\"{5}\", HardboundASIN=\"{6}\", PaperbackASIN=\"{7}\", ImgSrc=\"{8}\"}},", award, year, cat, title, author, kindleASIN, hardboundASIN, paperbackASIN, imgSrc);
```

Comment: Nice pickup! Completely missed that.